# Signature in LaTeX document

Tags: signatures

Is it possible to digitally sign a document in LaTeX?  Can I add an image to LaTeX's files so that I don't always have to add it to my working directory?  Are there better ways to add my signature?

Comment: Yes, you can add an image of a signature to your document using the `graphicx` package and `\includegraphics`. If you don't want to save your image in your working directory, you can always save it _anywhere_ on your computer and directly access it using the entire path of the image. For example, something like `\includegraphics{/Users/me/Documents/Signatures/filename}`.

Comment: Re. (1): By 'digitally sign' do you mean a proper digital signature of the kind Adobe Acrobat recognises? Or do you just want to include a picture of your signature? Re. (2): Yes. Re. (3): In which sense, for what purpose and by which criteria?

Comment: @Milo Or keep it in your personal tree. That's what I do.

Comment: @cfr . Personal tree?

Comment: `TEXMFHOME` ...